# Stretch nested panel to parent panel's width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nested bootstrap panel within another bootstrap panel (see image). How can I make the panel stretch to the width of the parent panel? To clarify, I don't want the nested panel to be the width of it's parent, but to stretch from wherever it is starting to the width of the parent panel.

So, if you look at the image, I want the panel to stretch to the right side (it would have a width of nearly half the parent panel).

If I were to shrink the width of the screen size, then the panel should go below the chart (which it currently does), and stretch to the right side.

Here's my code:

```
       <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border-color: #464646;">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="border-color: #BBBBBB; height: 35px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">Chart</div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <!--Chart-->
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <canvas id="myChart" width="325" height="325"></canvas>
                </div>

                <!--Panel to Stretch-->
                <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border-color: #464646;">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="border-color: #BBBBBB; height: 35px; padding-top: 3px;">
                            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about giving the chart and the nested panel a column class? Looks okay to me:

```
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border-color: #464646;">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="border-color: #BBBBBB; height: 35px; padding-top: 3px;">
            <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">Chart</div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <!--Chart-->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <canvas id="myChart" width="325" height="325"></canvas>
            </div>

            <!--Panel to Stretch-->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border-color: #464646;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="border-color: #BBBBBB; height: 35px; padding-top: 3px;">
                        <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Roka545 Glad it works. You might want to try wrapping the chart and nested panel with a `<div class="row">`. The row class has negative margins, which works well when nesting columns. Try this if the margins look incorrect.